# How can I add inject text into a ToC with the scope being a specific table of contents (\tableofcontents or \localtableofcontents)?

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks

## Question

How can I add text to a table of contents, yet limit its scope to that specific table, and whose format can be manipulated and does not have a page number?

## Conditions

- I can hide it from `\localtableofcontents`
- I can show it in a specific `\localtableofcontents` and hide from `\tableofcontents`
- I can add a bookmark to it (and a page reference to the page where the following content starts (in my case this would be the same page as Statement 1)

## Attempts

I realized shortly after trying to fulfill the first criterion that I was at a standstill. The following describes my attempt.

1. `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Special Documents}`
2. `\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{4ex}\protect\noindent\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\Huge\textcolor{red}{Special Documents}}\par}`

**Number 1** allows me to take advantage of the fact that my current setup makes parts only visible in the global ToC. This is not ideal, because it removes flexilibilty. Most importantly, this adds an entry, but the entry is not formatted and the entry also has a page number.

**Number 2** allows me to add a nice, formatted, non-numbered title to my table of contents. However, it adds it to every local table of contents, which is not good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\newcommand{\inputlanguage}[2]{%
    \newpage\pdfbookmark{#1}{bkm#1}%
    \etoctoccontentsline{part}{#1}%
    #2
}%
\newcommand{\inputotherdoc}[2]{%
    \newpage\pdfbookmark{#1}{bkm#1}%
    \etoctoccontentsline{part}{#1}%
    #2
}%

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0} % make ToC only contain Parts
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\protect\noindent\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\Huge\textcolor{red}{Language Directory}}\par} % In reality formatting is done with tocloft
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} % reset back to default for local ToCs
\newpage

\inputlanguage{da}{\localtableofcontents\section{At vove er, at miste fodfæstet for en stund ikke at vove er, at miste sig selv}}
\lipsum[1]
\inputlanguage{de}{\localtableofcontents\section{Wer rastet, der rostet.}}

\lipsum[1]
\inputlanguage{en}{\localtableofcontents\section{Education is what remains after one has forgotten what one has learned in school.}}
\lipsum[1]

% Problem is here
 \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Special Documents} % I need to inject text here and be able to: change font, change size, change, add new paragraphs, remove page number (imitate the the Language Directory text (using titlesec in original document)
 \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{4ex}\protect\noindent\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\Huge\textcolor{red}{Special Documents}}\par} % Second Attempt

 \inputotherdoc{Statement 1}{{\Huge Secret Information\par\bigskip}Here is some top-secret, specialized text.}
 \inputotherdoc{Statement 2}{{\Huge Specialized Information\par\bigskip}Here is some highly specialized text.}

\end{document}
```

## Output

In the example below, the "Special Documents" should only appear in the language ToC (`\tableofcontents`) and not in the local ToCs.
[image]

Comment: You can learn a lot by looking at the aux file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest technique is to add a command to the `.toc` file via `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\mycommand}` and then get this `\mycommand` to perform some action and redefine itself to do nothing. This needs no package.

However I use `etoc` to illustrate that the `\localtableofcontents` will not have the extra heading. (not shown in the image which only illustrates the main TOC)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{color}

% This will self-erase itself after first use
\newcommand*\SpecialDocumentsTocHeading
{\vspace{4ex}\noindent\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\Huge\textcolor{red}{Special
      Documents}}\par
 \global\let\SpecialDocumentsTocHeading\empty }

\begin{document}

% This Main TOC will have the Special Documents Heading.
\etocsettocdepth{section}
\tableofcontents

\part{ONE}
\chapter{Test chapter one}

\etocarticlestyle % resets default to use \section*, not \chapter* for TOC heading
\localtableofcontents

\section{Section one one}
\subsection{Subsection one one one}
\subsection{Subsection one  one two}
\section{Section one two}
\subsection{Subsection one two one}
\subsection{Subsection one  two two}

\chapter{Test chapter two}

\localtableofcontents

\section{Section two one}
\subsection{Subsection two one one}
\subsection{Subsection two one two}
\section{Section two two}
\subsection{Subsection two two one}
\subsection{Subsection two  two two}
\section{Section two three}
\subsection{Subsection two three one}
\subsection{Subsection two  three two}

\part{TWO}
\localtableofcontents

\chapter{Test chapter three}
\section{Section three one}
\subsection{Subsection three one one}
\subsection{Subsection three one two}

\chapter{Test chapter four}
\section{Section four one}
\subsection{Subsection four one one}
\subsection{Subsection four one two}
\subsection{Subsection four one three}
\section{Section four two}
\subsection{Subsection four two one}
\subsection{Subsection four two two}
\subsection{Subsection four two three}


\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\SpecialDocumentsTocHeading}
\chapter{Top secret information}

\chapter{Ultra top secret information}

\end{document}
```

[image: a toc]

If one needs the Special Documents in a later TOC, not the first one, then one should for example do in the preamble:

```
\newcommand*{\SpecialDocumentsTocHeadingActive}
    {\vspace{4ex}\noindent\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\Huge\textcolor{red}{Special
          Documents}}\par
     \global\let\SpecialDocumentsTocHeading\empty }
\newcommand*{\SpecialDocumentsTocHeading}{}
% or rather slightly more efficient \let\SpecialDocumentsTocHeading\empty
```

Then just before the TOC where one wants the Special Documents heading to appear one does:

```
\renewcommand*{\SpecialDocumentsTocHeading}{\SpecialDocumentsTocHeadingActive}
% or with a less LaTeX-like but a bit more efficient syntax:
% \let\SpecialDocumentsTocHeading\SpecialDocumentsTocHeadingActive
```

Comment: +1 But I am not using the book class. My entire document relies on the article class.

Comment: It seems that if I redefined the `\SpecialDocumentsTocHeading` to include an input `[1]`, I run into problems. The input will be shown without formatting in the local ToCs. I suppose the global `\empty` trick isn't working because of this. In the meantime, do you know what I can do to get this right? My idea for scalability would be to make a `\ToCGlobalHeadingInjector[1]` and a `\ToCLocalHeadingInjector[1]`.

Comment: I would not have mentioned it if it did not have some practical value. It makes sense to have flexibility at the input location `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\SpecialDocumentsTocHeading}` in your code like `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\SpecialDocumentsTocHeading{Special Documents}}`

Comment: `etoc` has other mechanisms which might functionally achieve what you want: specifically one could create a dummy sectioning unit and make it visible or not depending on the TOC. Do you want the extra TOC stuff to be tied to a specific TOC, or for example you could have `extraA`, `extraB`, `extraC` and one TOC could insert `extraA` and `extraB` but not `extraC` and another one `B` and `C` but not `A`? or it is something else you want, where each of your TOC has some private stuff not shown in others? the answer to these questions matter for the choice of method. Could you update your question?

Comment: How can you do the same with the list of figures and the list of tables?