# How to add text to TOC at a specific position in said TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, tocloft, article

This is a follow up to this discussion: [How can I add inject text into a ToC with the scope being a specific table of contents (\tableofcontents or \localtableofcontents)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234159/how-can-i-add-inject-text-into-a-toc-with-the-scope-being-a-specific-table-of-co)

I would like to add a line of text at a certain location to the TOC. My TOC currently looks like this

[image]

I would like to add the text "Page" at around this location

[image]

I am using PDFLATEX with the article class. Let me know if anything else is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. (No additional packages needed.)

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\bfseries Contents\hfill Page}   % added <<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Signature Block}

\section{Record of Revision}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

To add the word "Page" in the next line and changing the font size use

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\bfseries Contents\hfill \par \hfill {\normalsize Page}}
```

[image: d]

Comment: this works well for my question. I was wondering if you had any ideas on how to place the TOC title and the text "page" on separate lines? So for example, the TOC title would be on a line above the line containing the text "page"

Comment: @Austin Benny I added an update.

Comment: thank you! That helped